# Why zookeeper-cluster can not be linked through the ip address on host-pc?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

i'd like to study Dubbo on my mac and config all make-up ,but the log printed on console keep telling me connection error,so how could i fixed it?By the way ,the zookeeper-cluster was installed in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the zookeeper cookbook, zookeeper-cluster do not support linking through Docker.